# Display N numbers of table in ASP.NET webform based on user input

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, .net-4.5

I want to display N numbers of table in ASP.NET webform based on user input.

For example,

user input -> PDO123045,PDO122111

In this case, user input two values seperated by commas, so if I split the comma, I get length = 2. which are (PDO123045,PDO122111) in a list.
So I want to display two tables in asp webform.

2nd example,

user input -> PDO123045,PDO122111,PDO111345

In this case, user input two values seperated by commas, so if I split the comma, I get length = 3. which are (PDO123045,PDO122111,PDO111345) in a list.
So I want to display three tables in ASP.NET webform since user input three values.

I want to display N numbers of table in ASP.NET webform based on user input.

Comment: That's very interesting - but what is your question? What do you need help with?

Comment: The question was how to display a table for each value separated by a "," in the text box. Rather crystal clear what is being asked here. See my working code below for such an example of each value entered separated by a "," resulting in a table being displayed for each value entered into the text box.  Exactly as being asked here.

Comment: "I want to..." Is not a question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringBuilder` to compose it as HTML table and fill it into a `placeholder`.

So first, you gonna add a `placeholder` into your front end:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then at your code behind:

```
// split your input by comma
string[] stringArray = TextBox1.Text.Split(',');

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var str in stringArray)
{
    sb.Append($"<h2>{str}</h2>");

    // Now, build the appropriate table according to your data
    sb.Append($@"
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>");
}

// now display all tables to front end
ph1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(sb.ToString()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you can do it this way:

I don't have your data, but let's say we are to type in 1 city, or several.

And for each city we type in (separated by a comma), then we are to display a table for each city.

So, our markup can be this:

```
        Enter City(s) for Hotels: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Width="500px">
        </asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdShow" runat="server" 
            Text="Show City(s)"
            style="margin-left:30px"
            OnClick="cmdShow_Click"
            />

        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"
           OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="width: 50%">
                    <h3><%# $"Hotels For City = {Eval("City")}" %></h3>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
                        runat="server" CssClass="table">
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

And our code behind can be this:

```
Protected Sub cmdShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim rstMyCities As New DataTable
    rstMyCities.Columns.Add("City")

    Dim sCity As String = txtCity.Text.Replace(" ", "")
    For Each City As String In sCity.Split(",")
        Dim OneRow = rstMyCities.NewRow
        OneRow("City") = City
        rstMyCities.Rows.Add(OneRow)
    Next

    Repeater1.DataSource = rstMyCities
    Repeater1.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or
            e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

        Dim MyBindData As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem

        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(
            "SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description FROM tblHotelsA
            WHERE City = @City ORDER BY FirstName ")

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = MyBindData("City")

        Dim GV As GridView = e.Item.FindControl("GridView1")
        GV.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
        GV.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub
```

And the result is this:

[image]

And I used a helper routine (one gets VERY tired very fast typing over and over connection string code).

Hence, MyRstP simple returns a data table.

```
Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand) As DataTable


    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```